# Storing configuration data (json)

Tags: javascript, node.js

**tl;dr** Why storing configuration data in json files is considered a de facto standard?

I've recently read some parts of the [Maintainable Javascript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025245.do) book, specially the *Storing configuration data* chapter.

This is a quote from the chapter:

> Configuration data is best stored in a separate file to create a clean separation between
>   it and application logic. A good starting point is to have a separate JavaScript file for
>   configuration data. Once the configuration data is in a separate file, it opens up more
>   possibilities for managing that data. A worthwhile option is moving your configuration
>   data into a non-JavaScript file.
>
> Even though you’re writing a JavaScript application, JavaScript isn’t a great way to store
>   configuration data. That’s because the syntax is still that of a programming language,
>   so you need to be sure you haven't introduced syntax errors.

He basically says that storing configuration data in .json files or .js files is a bad practice and should be avoided.

From [json.org](http://www.json.org/):

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format.

Interchange means to me to send and receive data, to communicate two processes in a well-formatted way.

A lot of people are storing the data in json files, which adds a lot of noise: curly braces, indentation, double quotes, commas, cannot write comments, etc.

Java uses key-value lines, is there a simpler way to store this data?

```
a 1
```

And with json format (1):

```
{
  "a": 1
}
```

And with js format (2):

```
module.exports = {
  a: 1
}
```

Microsoft likes to use .ini files which add sections to these key-value lines.

Unix configuration files also use key-value lines.

Then, if all the world uses key-value lines because they are easy to read/write by humans, why are json files a de facto standard in the node.js world? Please don't tell me that's because json and javascript are practically synonyms and because developers are too lazy and prefer to call `require("./config.json")`.

In the above examples, the first option (1) was born to ease the data interchangeability. And the second, imo, it's just **bad**. This is the same as storing configuration data in a Java class. If I want to read this file from php because I have an apache server and nodejs for real-time things, how I'm supposed to parse that file? I'd need a javascript parser.

Both options shouldn't have syntax errors or the program might crash.

Comment: I take a different interpretation from the quote: it's saying that storing configuration in *JavaScript* (ie, .js files) is bad.  It's **not** saying that storing configuration in JSON is bad (it isn't).  **JSON != JavaScript.**

Comment: It saddens me that XML wasn't invited to the cage match er.. discussion...

Answer (score 3):

PS - IMHO you are right about comments, that's terrible to work with the format without comments

PPS - I'm Javascript developer, on post is Javascript tag - so answer subjectivelly from this side

**Why storing configuration data in JSON?**

It's very simple. **In Javascript.** Because JSON is formatted as an `Object` in JS, so you can have **the same syntax** for server-side objects, client-side objects and data stores. When you want to debug something, you can just grab whole JSON and put into your code like `var obj = JSON` and it works. You can find more on http://www.json.org/ Crockford's website.

**Why is important "a lot of noise as curly braces, identation, double quotes .." ?**

First reason is, of course, **the syntax error detection**. If you have strong syntax instead of "pure key/pair values" you are able to detect much faster and easily missing semicolons or braces. Also what is very important - parsing of big files is **faster**.

Second reason is different syntax for arrays, objects, strings and boolean. You want to have option of string "true", boolean true and number true - 1, because you want work with many databases, storages, APIs, programming languages - you need to **support the whole scale**.

Identation and JSON relationship **is not** an issue. JSON can be one-lined. In configuration files it's quite unpractical (users of stackoverflow can parse it ;DDD but "normal humans" no).

Third reason is parent-children relationship. Let's have a sample:

```
[
    {
        "email": "samuel@dude.com",
        "isAdmin" : true,
        "password": "KMLA#SLDOPW#",
        "modules" : [ "html", "js", "css" ],
        "creditcard" : {
            "number" : 3288942398329832,
            "expiration" : "2011-07-14T19:43:37+0100"
        }
    },
    {
        "email": "bill@dude.com",
        "isAdmin" : true,
        "password": "KMLA#SLDOPW#",
        "modules" : [ "js", "nodejs" ],
        "creditcard" : {
            "number" : 20432943092423,
            "expiration" : "2011-07-14T19:43:37+0100"
        }
    },
    {
        "email": "thomas@dude.com",
        "isAdmin" : false,
        "password": "KMLA#SLDOPW#",
        "modules" : [ "ruby", "python", "css" ],
        "creditcard" : {
            "number" : 4239093223423,
            "expiration" : "2011-07-14T19:43:37+0100"
        }
    }
]
```

.. do you want to log all emails into console?
`jsonobj.forEach(function(ele){ console.log(ele.email); });`

.. do you want have access to first user's credit card number?
`jsonobj[0].creditcard.number`

.. do you want to add next user?
`jsonobj.push({ email: "peter@dude.com:, isAdmin: false })`

.. do you want to parse file without external library?
`JSON.parse(jsonrawfile);`

**JSON vs. XML**

Very simular way is to have XML. But about this try to google some differences. I think front-end developers are as fans XML as fans IE6. There is more reasons why its like that. **Try google for it.**

Hope that it quite helped.